# Manual "SAVE UNAVAILABLE" in Hogwarts Legacy

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I am trying to manually save my game in Hogwarts Legacy, but I'm getting this error:

[image: "SAVE UNAVAILABLE" in Hogwarts Legacy]

It says that manual saving is currently unavailable and that autosaves may still be performed during this time.

Other users on [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/990080/discussions/0/3761104682790096408/) are also having this issue.

Why is this? Why can't I manually save my game?

Comment: Hi. I wanted to bring up some concerns that have been raised by members of the community regarding the frequency and quality of your questions. I think it would be helpful for you to take a look at the following [meta] post: "[Users asking (and self-answering) in blocks](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16835/4797)", where these concerns are being discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This could be multiple reasons

### Reason 1

Some parts of the game you cannot manually save. Like some parts of a quest or some areas where things are happening.

For example, you cannot save during the prologue i.e. during the Road to Hogwarts story quest. Creating manual saves will be unlocked once you find yourself for the first time in the chambers of the chosen House in Hogwarts. Similar situations may appear in chosen moments in the further parts of the game.

### Reason 2

If your computer's current date and time are set to an older date and time than your latest save's date and time. Your computer's date and time need to be newer than your game's last date and time in order to perform a manual save.

### Reason 3

Could be a bug in the game. In that case you need to wait for the developers to fix it.